# How to store images into browser cache in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, image, caching, store

I am working on a website that is build with the use of AngularJs.
But the problem is website have many images and whenever someone reload the page its call the server to send the images source.
I want to saved all the images (which are loaded multiple time) in the browser cache and fetch it whenever the user come again on my website, but firstly website should check for the browser cache if images are present then load it, if not then call the server.

Comment: what does your server request looks like? If you have `$http.get` you can try adding `cache: true` to its config

Answer (score 3):

Please try this - use application cache manifest - read more about it here developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/… I am using it for my offline app with angular and it's working :) It got it's gotyas so watch out (update manifest file every time you change something - add version counter in beginning of file)